# Java UnZip program

Tags: java, unzip, zip

I have a zip file with the following structure:

```
MyZip.zip
|-- FOLDER_1
|   `-- FOLDER_11
|       |-- file_a
|       `-- file_b
|-- FOLDER_2
|   `-- FOLDER_22
|       `-- file_c
`-- FOLDER_3
    `-- FOLDER_33
        `-- file_d
```

I have tried to use this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/) but it doesn't work with my zip structure. What do I need to chage to make that class unzip my zip file properly? It will create C:\outputzip\FOLDER1\FOLDER_11 where FOLDER_11 isn't a folder, yet a file caled FOLDER_11 and then the program breaks.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class UnZip {
    List<String> fileList;
    private static final String INPUT_ZIP_FILE = "C:\\MyFile.zip";
    private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "C:\\outputzip";

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        UnZip unZip = new UnZip();
        unZip.unZipIt(INPUT_ZIP_FILE,OUTPUT_FOLDER);
    }

    /**
    * Unzip it
    * @param zipFile input zip file
    * @param output zip file output folder
    */
    public void unZipIt(String zipFile, String outputFolder){
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try{
            //create output directory is not exists
            File folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER);
            if(!folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            //get the zip file content
            ZipInputStream zis = 
            new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
            //get the zipped file list entry
            ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

            while(ze!=null){
                String fileName = ze.getName();
                File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

                System.out.println("file unzip : "+ newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

                //create all non exists folders
                //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
                new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);             

                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                fos.close();   
                ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            }

            zis.closeEntry();
            zis.close();

            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Include your code **in the question** (question will become invalid if the linked page changes).

Comment: You have to check, if the ZipEntry is a directory. You treat every entry as a file.

Comment: This code looks suspiciously like the code found at:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your while() loop to below and play around if you will have some problems:

```
        while (ze != null) {

            String fileName = ze.getName();
            File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator
                    + fileName);

            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                File directory = new File(newFile.getPath());
                directory.mkdirs();
                ze = zis.getNextEntry();
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println("file unzip : " + newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            fos.close();
            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
```

Comment: Or in other words: a ZipEntry might be just a directory, and the original turns that zip entry erroneously into a file.